# Histogram with marginal boxplot with ggExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, boxplot

Hello I want a marginal boxplot to a histogram. Like a year ago I could do it with the same code below

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggExtra)

    set.seed(17)

    x <- rpois(10000,lambda = 2)


    c <- ggplot() + 
      geom_histogram(aes(x),fill='lightblue',closed='left', bins = 10)+
      geom_vline(xintercept= quantile(x),linetype = 3,colour = "Red")+
      theme_bw()

    d <- ggMarginal(c, type = "boxplot", fill="lightblue",colour='blue',margins='x',size=30)

    d
```

Clearly the boxplot doesn´t correspond to what it is supposed to. I know there are other ways to put the two draws together, but unless you know a more elegant graph... I appreciate any help with ggExtra.

Best regards,

Peter

Comment: I open an issue in the package github page, github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/131 There you can see what I could do in the past and that now it doesn't work. The owners are not interested in updating this behavior.

Comment: Z. Lin has done it! thank you so much. Now it's a matter of including this function in a package so we all can use it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743081/add-geom-rug-like-boxplots-per-group-in-ggplot2/52925520). See if this look works for you? The boxplot is *inside* the plot margins (similar to `geom_rug`), rather than outside.

```
c +
  geom_marginboxplot(aes(x, y = 1), sides = "t", 
                     fill = "lightblue", colour = "blue")
```

[image: plot]

Code for `geom_marginboxplot` is in the link above.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I wanted. It would be perfect to include this function in a package so that we don't have to source it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The x-axis is just a set of 10 values. It's the y-axis that has the distribution aspects. So that boxplot is correct, ... but trivial at best and misleading at worst. What you want (or should want) is:

```
d <- ggMarginal(cc, type = "boxplot", 
fill="lightblue",colour='blue',margins='y',size=30)

 d
```

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. I want a boxplot for x, the variable under study. I should NOT want a boxplot for the counts (y margin).

Comment: I open an issue in the package github page,

https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/131

There you can see what I could do in the past and that now it doesn't work. The owners are not interested in updating this behavior so if any one knows how to put a histogram and a boxplot together I'd appriciate your help. Thank you very much.